# subbottom of memoir puts margin around minipages

Tags: memoir, subfloats, minipage

I have many figures in my document that consists of some minipages which take up the full textwidth. Now I wanted two of these figures to appear combined as subfigures. Since the document is in memoir, I decided to give subbottom a try. Unfortunately, subbottom in combination with minipage sets a margin around the figure, and I do not know how to get rid of it. That means, the figure cannot have the full textwidth. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subbottom{
\begin{minipage}{.495\textwidth}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.495\textwidth}
b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
\end{minipage}
}
\end{figure}

a
\end{document}
```

[image: The figure is moved to the right]

As can be seen in relation to the rule, the figure is a little bit shifted to the right.
If I omit the subbottom, everything is fine. And if I omit the minipage, the text inside the subbottom also starts at the left end. But in combination it does not work.

Comment: Did you already try with `\subbottom{%
\begin{minipage}{.495\textwidth}`  and `\end{minipage}%
}`? This should help getting rid of the overfull box warning and the undesired indentation.

Comment: Ah, right, that was it. Thank you very much!